# How do Power and Compassion affect my abilities?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I know that Power increases the damage of direct abilities, Condition Damage improves conditions, and Healing Power (Compassion) improves the heal effects. But by how much?

- Do damaging abilities get a linear bonus to damage based on your power? (Does +1 power = +1 damage?)
- Do healing abilities get a linear bonus to healing based on your compassion? (Does +1 compassion = +1 to heals?)
- How does Compassion interact with the Regeneration buff? (Heal over Time)
- Several skills trigger life leech, such as the Rune of the Vampirism. Does this leech effect scale with your healing?
- Dark Fields can cause life leech as well - do those also scale with Compassion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wiki actually has quite some information on this!

**Power** is a simple one: 
Each attribute point put into this attribute increases the attack statistic by one, which increases damage for all attacks. [source](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Power)

This however, leads us to want to figure out how attack actually works. And how damage is calculated from this. We know that attack is a simple calculation: weapon damage + power.

Currently, we do not have any certainty about the calculations of how attack is used to calculate the damage of abilities however.

**Healing power or compassion (same thing!):**
Each point of Healing Power adds 0.1258 healing for Regeneration, 0.0643 healing for Rejuvenation, and it is unknown how much healing is added for active healing skills.
[source](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Healing_Power)

According to the wiki, Life leech is indeed affected by healing power. I however got no idea if dark fields also scale, and if they do on who they scale.